# Java Regex ignoring newline character WITHOUT Dotall

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse returned emails for a specific object id. The problem is that, when the email is returned, the id may be split into several lines. Usually it should look like this:

```
foo#bar-20130101-103000#12345
```

whereat I'm interested in the last part "12345". The problem is that that string tends to be split by a newline, for example:

```
foo#bar-20130101-103000#12
345
```

which causes my regex

```
[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1,5}#[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1,5}-\d{8}-\d{6}#(\d+)
```

to only find "12" instead of "12345". Now all the hints i find on the 'net are to use Pattern.MULTILINE and/or Pattern.DOTALL, but multiline only influences the ^ and $ anchors and dotall only makes . match on newline chars too. The problem is that i don't have a . here and it's not really applicable either, because i only want digits.
So how can i make my regex match the whole thing and not stop at the line break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\d\r\n]` will match a digit or a new line, so try with `([\d\r\n]+)`.

Comment: I've replaced \d with [\d\r\n], it does bloat the regex pretty much but it works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your number is in the end you can try:

```
"(?s)^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1,5}#[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1,5}-\d{8}-\d{6}#(.*)$"
```

i.e. capture everything after `#` with `DOTALL`

Following should also work without `DOTALL`:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1,5}#[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1,5}-\d{8}-\d{6}#[\\d\\r\\n]+$"
```